# Using Microsoft.Build.Evaluation to publish a database project (.sqlproj)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, msbuild-propertygroup, sql-server-data-tools

I need to be able to publish an SSDT project programmatically. I am looking at using Microsoft.Build to do so but can not find any documentation. It seems pretty simple to create the .dacpac, but how would I either publish to an existing database or at the very least to a .sql file. The idea is to have it do what it does when I right click on the project and select publish. It should compare with a selected database and generate an upgrade script.

This is what I have so far to create the .dacpac:

```
partial class DBDeploy
{
  Project project;


  internal void publishChanges()
  {
     Console.WriteLine("Building project " + ProjectPath);
     Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
     sw.Start();

     project = ProjectCollection.GlobalProjectCollection.LoadProject(ProjectPath);
     project.Build();
     //at this point the .dacpac is built and put in the debug folder for the project

     sw.Stop();
     Console.WriteLine("Project build Complete.  Total time: {0}", sw.Elapsed.ToString());

  }
}
```

Essentially I am trying to do what this [MSBuild Example](http://sqlproj.com/index.php/2012/03/headless-msbuild-support-for-ssdt-sqlproj-projects/) shows but in code.

Sorry that this is all I have. The doecumentation on the Build classes is very poor. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 20):

I had to do something similar to this because VSDBCMD which we previously used does not deploy to SQL Server 2012 and we needed to support it. What I found was the Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac assembly which seems to come as part of the SQL Server data tools (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/tools.aspx)

When you run this on the client machine you will need the full version of the .NET 4 framework and the SQL CLR types and SQL T-SQL ScriptDOM pack found here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29065

Code below is from a mockup I made for testing the new deployment method and deploys a given .dacpac file

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac;
    using System.IO;

    namespace ConsoleApplication3
    {
        class Program
        {
            private static TextWriter output = new StreamWriter("output.txt", false);
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {

                Console.Write("Connection String:");
                //Class responsible for the deployment. (Connection string supplied by console input for now)
                DacServices dbServices = new DacServices(Console.ReadLine());

                //Wire up events for Deploy messages and for task progress (For less verbose output, don't subscribe to Message Event (handy for debugging perhaps?)
                dbServices.Message += new EventHandler<DacMessageEventArgs>(dbServices_Message);
                dbServices.ProgressChanged += new EventHandler<DacProgressEventArgs>(dbServices_ProgressChanged);


                //This Snapshot should be created by our build process using MSDeploy
                Console.WriteLine("Snapshot Path:");

                DacPackage dbPackage = DacPackage.Load(Console.ReadLine());




                DacDeployOptions dbDeployOptions = new DacDeployOptions();
                //Cut out a lot of options here for configuring deployment, but are all part of DacDeployOptions
                dbDeployOptions.SqlCommandVariableValues.Add("debug", "false");


                dbServices.Deploy(dbPackage, "trunk", true, dbDeployOptions);
                output.Close();

            }

            static void dbServices_Message(object sender, DacMessageEventArgs e)
            {
                output.WriteLine("DAC Message: {0}", e.Message);
            }

            static void dbServices_ProgressChanged(object sender, DacProgressEventArgs e)
            {
                output.WriteLine(e.Status + ": " + e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

This seems to work on all versions of SQL Server from 2005 and up. There is a similar set of objects available in Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Dac, however I believe this is in the previous version of DACFx and is not included in the latest version. So use the latest version if you can.

Comment: Brilliant, using the DACPAC assemblies allow me to take full control of the deployment. Also useful for integration tests!

Comment: Finally, a sensible answer! Thanks - Just want to add that you need to copy/reference the `sqlserver.dac.dll` from  `Microsoft Visual Studio ??.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\DAC\120` - Works really well, exactly what I needed, so simple and fast. This should be accepted!

Comment: Any experience with setting the flag "upgradeExisting" to false? I get an exception telling me "Cannot deploy to existing database when upgrading has been disabled". But I want DacServices to remove the database first. It doesn't work, even if I add options with CreateNewDatabase = true

Comment: @Peter - there is an overload for upgradeExisting:  services.Deploy(package, connectionString, upgradeExisting: true);

Answer (score 3):

We need a way tell msbuild how and where to publish. Open your project in Visual Studio and begin to `Publish` it. Enter all needed info in the dialog, including your DB connection info and any custom SQLCMD variable values. `Save Profile As...` to a file, e.g. Northwind.publish.xml. (You may then `Cancel`.) Now we can use this and the project file to build and publish:

```
// Create a logger.
FileLogger logger = new FileLogger();
logger.Parameters = @"logfile=Northwind.msbuild.log";
// Set up properties.
var projects = ProjectCollection.GlobalProjectCollection;
projects.SetGlobalProperty("Configuration", "Debug");
projects.SetGlobalProperty("SqlPublishProfilePath", @"Northwind.publish.xml");
// Load and build project.
var dbProject = ProjectCollection.GlobalProjectCollection.LoadProject(@"Northwind.sqlproj");
dbProject.Build(new[]{"Build", "Publish"}, new[]{logger});
```

This can take awhile and may appear to get stuck. Be patient. :)

Comment: I needed to reference both the `Microsoft.Build` and `Microsoft.Build.Framework` assemblies for this code to work.

Comment: Make sure to check the return value of `Build` to see if it was successful or not.

Comment: To monitor build events, use a `ConfigurableForwardingLogger` and set `BuildEventRedirector` to a custom `IEventRedirector`. You can check for errors by checking if `buildEvent` is a `BuildErrorEventArgs`.

Comment: Its ok if you want to publish to one DB the whole time, but the DAC seems to allow me to target any server, or databases, so I can create and drop databases as needed, based on the DACPAC.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [SqlPackage.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh550080%28v=vs.103%29.aspx?ppud=4) to publish your dacpac.

```
SqlPackage.exe 
  /Action:Publish 
  /SourceFile:C:/file.dacpac 
  /TargetConnectionString:[Connection string]
```

Also instead of passing too many parameters you could save your settings into DAC Publish Profile (this can be done from visual studio)

Comment: `should` ... should be `could` :)

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to build and publish a database based on a sqlproj file and log helpful information to console. Here's what I arrived at:

```
using Microsoft.Build.Framework;
using Microsoft.Build.Execution;

public void UpdateSchema() {
    var props = new Dictionary<string, string> {
        { "UpdateDatabase", "True" },
        { "PublishScriptFileName", "schema-update.sql" },
        { "SqlPublishProfilePath", "path/to/publish.xml") }
    };

    var projPath = "path/to/database.sqlproj";

    var result = BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.Build(
        new BuildParameters { Loggers = new[] { new ConsoleLogger() } },
        new BuildRequestData(new ProjectInstance(projPath, props, null), new[] { "Publish" }));

    if (result.OverallResult == BuildResultCode.Success) {
        Console.WriteLine("Schema update succeeded!");
    }
    else {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.WriteLine("Schema update failed!");
        Console.ResetColor();
    }
}

private class ConsoleLogger : ILogger
{
    public void Initialize(IEventSource eventSource) {
        eventSource.ErrorRaised += (sender, e) => {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            Console.ResetColor();
        };
        eventSource.MessageRaised += (sender, e) => {
            if (e.Importance != MessageImportance.Low)
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        };
    }
    public void Shutdown() { }
    public LoggerVerbosity Verbosity { get; set; }
    public string Parameters { get; set; }
}
```

This is for .NET 4 and above. Be sure and include assembly references to **Microsoft.Build** and **Microsoft.Build.Framework**.