# Poor MSBuild performance when deploying SSDT DB project programmatically

Tags: visual-studio-2010, performance, msbuild, sql-server-data-tools, localdb

I have an SSDT database project. I've set up a publish profile that publishes it to an SQL Server 2012 *localdb* instance. I have found [some code that can be used to publish the database programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10933456/238753):

First import these:

```
using Microsoft.Build.Evaluation;
using Microsoft.Build.Logging;
using Microsoft.Build.Framework;
```

Then publish the DB:

```
// Create a logger.
FileLogger logger = new FileLogger();
logger.Parameters = @"logfile=Northwind.msbuild.log";

// Set up properties.
var projects = ProjectCollection.GlobalProjectCollection;
projects.SetGlobalProperty("Configuration", "Debug");
projects.SetGlobalProperty("SqlPublishProfilePath", @"Northwind.publish.xml");

// Load and build project.
var dbProject = ProjectCollection.GlobalProjectCollection.LoadProject(@"Northwind.sqlproj");
dbProject.Build(new[]{"Build", "Publish"}, new[]{logger});
```

When I use Visual Studio 2010 to manually publish the database using the publish profile shown in the code, it takes about 4-10 seconds. However, when I run this code to programmatically do the same thing, it takes about 40 seconds.

I have tried removing the *Build* target, but this didn't make a noticeable difference.

Why is the performance of the programmatic option poorer? What can I do to achieve the same performance as a manual publish?

Comment: you could try with Process.Start( "msbuild", "/p:Configuration=Debug .... /t:Build;Publish" ); if that's ok for your use case

Comment: @stijn, that had the same performance as the code in the question.

Comment: hmm, so it's purely an msbuild vs VisualStudio problem? in that case: turn on detailed or diagnostic logging and try to figure out where the delay occurs?

Comment: May want to try building the dacpac using MSBuild then publishing using SQLPackage. That may make a difference.

Comment: @PeterSchott, that had similar performance to the code in the question.