# Create dacpac file programmatically from SSDT project

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2014, sql-server-data-tools, sql-server-data-project

Is it possible to create a 'fresh' `.dacpac` file from an existing SSDT project? I would like to be able to recreate the database (teardown + setup) before each automatic end-to-end test:

```
const string dacPacFileName = @"D:\Bla.dacpac";
var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BlaConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

var dacPackage = DacPackage.Load(dacPacFileName);
var dacServices = new DacServices(connectionString);      
var dacOptions = new DacDeployOptions();
dacOptions.CreateNewDatabase = true;
dacServices.Deploy(dacPackage, "Bla", true, dacOptions);
```

Comment: Have you looked at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10438258/using-microsoft-build-evaluation-to-publish-a-database-project-sqlproj ?

Comment: @DavidTansey - sorry but at which point does the code there create the required ('fresh') dacpac file needed above at const string dacPacFileName = @"D:\Bla.dacpac";?

Comment: maybe I can publish the ssdt project directly rather than use a dacpac file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done this using PowerShell by calling something like

```
> msbuild.exe <mysolution>.sln /p:Configuration=<myconfig>
```

This will build the solution and should make the dacpac.

After that I call

```
> sqlpackage.exe /Action:<someaction> /SourceFile:<thatdacpac> /Profile:<publishprofile>
```

but you might just need the first step if you are deploying the dacpac as opposed to doing schema compare and publish. Does that help at all?

Comment: Excellent. I was hoping I can do this 'purely programmatically' (as in C# see example in my question) but never mind (-:

Answer (score 2):

```
var process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
var startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
{
    WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
    FileName = @"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DAC\bin\SqlPackage.exe",
    Arguments = "/TargetFile:D:/output_target.dacpac /Action:Extract 
                /SourceServerName:ServerName /SourceDatabaseName:DatabaseName 
                /SourceUser:UserId /SourcePassword:Password"
};
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Use this code inside a method and try it. Don't forget to replace your data with the fields

Comment: You can create dacpac from existing database